# Solve complex equation $|z|^5=z^5$ for $z$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, education

I have a problem, this equation should be solved for $z$, with $z$ being complex. There should be $5$ solutions bc of the exponent. I already got the solutions from WolframAlpha, but dont know how to get there.

Comment: Did you try writing $z=a+bi$ and then writing down the two equations in $a$ and $b$?

Comment: There will be many more than $5$ solutions. For example, this equation is satisfied for any real number. And if $z$ is a solution, then so is $rz$ for any $r\in\mathbb R$. This is *not* a polynomial (because of the absolute value sign) so there is no reason to expect there to just be $5$ solutions.

Comment: @Mathmo123 To be precise, if $z$ is a solution, then $rz$ is a solution for all $r\in\mathbb R_{\ge0}$. In fact, the equation is satisfied by all non-negative real numbers. Of course, this detail does not change one bit the point of what you said.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli yes of course. Thanks. I'll leave the comment up, as the point still stands!

Comment: $|z|^5$ is $|z^5|$. So first solve $|a|=a$ and then solve $z^5=a$ for all valid $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $|z|^5$ is non-negative and real so any solution to the equation $|z|^5 = z^5$ has that $z^5$ is non-negative and real. Furthermore, any non-negative and real number clearly satisfies the equation. So it is sufficient and necessary that $z^5$ is non-negative and real.

Zero is one solution. As for the remaining solutions, recall that in the complex plane, raising a nonzero complex number to the $5$th power multiplies the angle it forms with the positive real axis by 5. And it is sufficient and necessary that the resulting angle be 0. So it is sufficient and necessary that the original angle is a multiple of $\frac{2\pi}{5}$.

In other words, the solutions plotted in the complex plane are the rotations of the non-negative real axis by the 5 angles that are multiples of $\frac{2\pi}{5}$.

Answer (score 0):

Writing $z=re^{i\theta}$ then $|z|^5=z^5\iff r^5=r^5e^{i5\theta}\iff e^{i5\theta}=1$ or $r=0$.

This equation solves to $z=0$ or $4\theta=2k\pi\iff \theta=\dfrac{2k\pi}5$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$.

This simply describe all positive real axis half-lines rotated by multiples of $\frac{2\pi}{5}$ angle.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** Left side is real non-negative, so the same is true for $z^5$. Use the $r,\phi$ notation of complex number and geometric interpretation of a product.